# Why is my private route checkup always evaluating to false?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a private route component in my react app

```
    import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

export default ({ component: Component, render: renderFn, authed, ...rest }) =>
  Component ? (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authed === true ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />
          )
      }
    />
  ) : (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => authed === true ? console.log(authed) : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} /> } /> 
    );
```

Which works with the following routes

```
<PrivateRoute authed={this.state.isAuthenticated} path="/route1" render={props => <iframe frameBorder={0} src={constans.urlRoute1} className="iframe" />} />
<PrivateRoute authed={this.state.isAuthenticated} path='/register' component={RegisterPage} />
```

The problem im facing is that they always evaluate to false because my app.js doesnt have time to set the state of authentication, the router acts too fast.

This is how the resto of my auth process looks in the app.js

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log("PROPS APPJS")
    console.log(props)

    //checks if user is autheticated within the system in order to manage routes
    this.state = {
        isAuthenticated: false 
    }  

}


componentDidMount() {
    isAuthenticated().then((result) => {
        if (result === true) {
            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true})
        } else {
            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: false})
        }
    });
}
```

How can I make the protected route await for componentDidMount() to set the proper value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either not return anything before authentication check in your `app.js` or you can move the authentication logic into the private route handler and wait for it to finish and then decide.

The first option would be something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        authenticationChecked: false,
        isAuthenticated: false 
    }  

}


componentDidMount() {
    isAuthenticated().then((result) => {
        if (result === true) {
            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true, authenticationChecked: true})
        } else {
            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: false, authenticationChecked: true})
        }
    });
}

render() {
    if (!this.state.authenticationChecked) return null; // Or some sort of loader ...
    // Render the app otherwise
}
```

@pgsandstrom's answer is also another way to handle the problem. But I usually rather avoid synchronous calls so I have the freedom to show a loader or ... while the function is working.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `isAuthenticated()` method is asynchronous, so your component will always render before it is done. If you can make it synchronous, then do so and run it directly in the constructor.

If you cannot make it synchronous, then your only option is to block rendering until you have your result. You could do this by having a "isLoading" state that returns early from your render method if it is true. Then set it to false at the same time as you set your `isAuthenticated` state.

Comment: In fact thats the reason, and now that you have commented the isLoading stuff ive a grasp of what to do now. Thanks